# how to get url in html , document.referrer is empty

Tags: javascript, html

Please help to get current URL from which this page is called ? what is wrong with this ?, becaz alert comes with empty.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function check()
{
alert(document.referrer);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="check()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get what URL? If the referrer is empty, then it is because there isn't one.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? Referrer checking is not usually a fruitful task

Comment: just wanted current url from which this page is called.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies

Comment: Just updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) `document.referrer`

> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark).

You if want to get the current page url then you can use the

```
window.location.href
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your alert with any one of these method.It will work.

```
alert(document.URL)
alert(window.location.href)
alert(document.location.href)
alert(window.location.pathname)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){    
     alert(Window.location.href);
};
```

or if you want to go for particular URL do this

```
function test(){    
    $(window.location).attr('href', '../your link');

};
```

Answer (score 1):

To get URL use,

```
var url = window.location.href;
```